# Build system for .cpp files : run make.bat in the same folder

Tags: makefile, sublimetext2, sublimetext

How to make that <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> (Build) automatically launches the `make.bat` file in the same folder, when editing a .cpp file in Sublime Text?

Note: I've found *Tools > Build system > New build system* but I haven't achieved to do it yet.

Comment: Did you try reading the fine [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with this `C++.sublime-build` in `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\C++` (Windows 7) :

```
{
    "cmd": ["$file_path\\make.bat"]
}
```